# Buttons Are Dependent With Their Position

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a screen which has five buttons and five check box. But this buttons dependent each other with their positions on the screen. For example , In `XML` file, If I change position of first button , the other buttons and `checkBoxes` position change too . But I don't want this. I want changes only one button position.

**This is my XML file :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonN381 "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttoN291 "
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:onClick="kelimeGösterimi"
        android:text="31 - 40" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttoN291 "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:onClick="kelimeGösterimi"
        android:text="41 - 50" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttoN371"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonN381 "
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox4"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/checkBox4"
        android:onClick="kelimeGösterimi"
        android:text="21 - 30" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttoN611"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttoN371"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox5"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/checkBox5"
        android:onClick="kelimeGösterimi"
        android:text="11 - 20" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttoN601"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttoN611"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkBox6"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/checkBox6"
        android:onClick="kelimeGösterimi"
        android:text="1 - 10" />


    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonN381 "
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttonN381 "
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonN381 " />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttoN371"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttoN371"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttoN371" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttoN611"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttoN611"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttoN611" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttoN601"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttoN601"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttoN601" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/buttoN601"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttoN601"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="11dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use linear layout or put your require layout sketch so i can help you

Answer (score 0):

Sure if you try to move any button this will affect the other views because you'r using RelativeLayout and you assign above, belwo, toLeftOf, toRightOf ...etc
this parameters links the views together
for clear understanding of RelativeLayout [see this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html)

to solve this issue you have many solutions just try to read about **Android Layouts** topic

i will give you a simple solution now using LinearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0do"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonn381"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="kelimeGösterimi"
            android:text="31 - 40" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button291"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="kelimeGösterimi"
            android:text="41 - 50" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button371"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="kelimeGösterimi"
            android:text="21 - 30" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button611"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="kelimeGösterimi"
            android:text="11 - 20" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button601"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="kelimeGösterimi"
            android:text="1 - 10" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        >
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```